# cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli/ngc' when I run ng serve

Tags: angular, npm

my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "cal-euc",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "^7.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "^7.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.0.1",
    "@angular/http": "^7.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.0.1",
    "@angular/router": "^7.0.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.4",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.25",
    "@angular/cli": "^8.3.25",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.0.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "^7.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^4.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~3.1.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. Please use markdown syntax to format your question, and make it more readable. I already edited it. Explain also a little more your issue, not only question title. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had same problem. It's because angular-cli version is greater than angular version and  compiler-cli is not compatible.
I downgraded angular-cli version to 7 and my project now works without problems.

I couldn't find any other solution.

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g @angular/cli@7.3.9
```

Regards

Comment: What are the steps you followed to down grade to 7? Can you please provide it here.